# Correct slang term for "overturn/lay" server by load?

Tags: word-request

What is a correct slang term for "overturn/lay down" server by load?

(also would be interested in professional term)

Answer (score 1):

Intent can make a difference in this case, so it depends on context.

In a normal case, for example if a page on your server has become very popular and is receiving a huge number of requests, you would use the term **'overloading the server'** to describe the server failing due to not being able to process that many requests.

If there is malicious intent, for example a DDos attack, you could use the term **'flooding the server'** to describe the deliberate action of a person or persons to overload a server by exhausting the server's resources.

Another, non-specific term that could be used is **'crashing the server'**, and I've also seen '[**slashdotting the server**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slashdot_effect)' in use, though I would guess it wouldn't be a familiar term to many.